# System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException using xunit2 and automapper

Tags: .net, automapper, xunit2

I have been facing an unusual problem, in my unit test project I am getting this error, also the strange thing is some tests which normally pass, fail in next run. With this error I am also getting AutoMapperMappingExceptions, although I am trying to load all the profiles from the assembly. I have checked my app.config too for potential errors. I am running xunit2, automapper 3.2.1. I am attaching part of the stack trace

```
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
    Configuration system failed to initialize
    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
    at System.Web.Configuration.ClientRuntimeConfig.GetSectionObject(String sectionName)
    at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex index)
    at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_HttpRuntime()
    at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.GetCustomEncoderFromConfig()
    at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
    at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.get_Current()
    at System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(String s)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a framework error, it has nothing to do with AM. A malformed configuration file would cause this for example. There should be an inner exception with more details.

Comment: what do u mean by malformed configuration file ? I have checked app.config and package.config already.